# Why So much Disk space For the Content databases?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint 2013 Farm that is used mostly for Files, not much of anything else.

I ran a PS to collect the files  sizes of all the files. I ended with 1.7 million files with total size of ~3 terabytes.

On the other hand, I ran a PS to give me the sizes of the databases. It came out to be 10 terabyte.

How can I explain such inefficiency? is there something I can do to the databases?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is older versions occupy more than the current versions.